# Updating an application from git resource after modifying files

Tags: git

How do I pull down the latest updates from a git repository and not mess up the files I modified?  And I don't want to mess up anything on the author's git repository either.

Suppose there is a security application someone has written and shared on git..

I run git clone https://applicationurl.git
and download it.
I modify the config file to work on my network.

So months later when I hear there's an update I run
git status

and get ...

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)

```
    modified:   elastalert/config.py
```

which is the file I modified from the original.  BUT if I do git add I'm not messing up anything on the author's git page?

Just to get it to work I just cp'ed it to home, deleted the file, and then ran

git pull

copied the file back over from home and now it's good to go.

BUT how do I do this the 'git' way?  I'm still a novice at this and don't want to mess up the author's original code in git.

How can I make changes to a config file and still get the latest updates from the repository?

Many thanks...the git documentation makes my head spin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create a branch and commit your local changes:

```
$ git checkout -b myconfig
# edit config.py
$ git add elastalert/config.py
$ git commit -m "My Configuration"
```

Once you have that, you can pull (or fetch and rebase) the author's master branch:

```
$ git fetch origin
$ git rebase origin/master
```

Comment: Alright, so if I create a 'branch' with checkout -b, and commit my changes with 'git add' that has nothing to do with the author's master branch and nothing I do will mess that up, then I can keep the software updated with the authors repository?

By contrast, say I was working on the repository with someone and I DO want to update/rewrite code is that 'fork"

Comment: Anything you do locally will not affect the author's repository until you `git push` to it (and depending on how exactly the repository is set up, such changes will usually be reviewed before being merged back to the original `master` branch). From a technical perspective, you've created a fork once you have changes the original repository doesn't have, but that term is usually only used if you publish those change (and usually if you don't merge, or at least, intend to merge them back to the original repository).